# Is there any way it Run a Selenium Project without eclispe?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, webdriver

I Have to give a Demo to my Client  is there anyway to run Selenium web driver project without installing any IDE like Eclipse

If so Please let me know how to can be done

Comment: Yes, it's possible. You can use the `command prompt` to run the scripts based on the framework. Can you share more details on your framework, are you using POM? is it TestNg based?

Comment: possibly by running with a  jar